# Error while starting Bro

Tags: bro

I am trying to install Bro on my machine running Ubuntu 16.04 and I am facing the following problem on bro start. It has multiple errors and kindly assist on how to resolve them.

```
[BroControl] > start
starting bro (was crashed) ...
bro terminated immediately after starting; check output with "diag"
[BroControl] > diag
[bro]

Bro 2.4.1
Linux 4.4.0-36-generic


==== No reporter.log

==== stderr.log
    fatal error: problem with interface eth0 (eth0: SIOCETHTOOL(ETHTOOL_GET_TS_INFO) ioctl failed: No such device)

==== stdout.log
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited

==== .cmdline
-i eth0 -U .status -p broctl -p broctl-live -p standalone -p local -p bro local.bro broctl broctl/standalone broctl/auto

==== .env_vars
PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/share/broctl/scripts:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
BROPATH=/var/spool/bro/installed-scripts-do-not-touch/site::/var/spool/bro/installed-scripts-do-not-touch/auto:/usr/share/bro:/usr/share/bro/policy:/usr/share/bro/site
CLUSTER_NODE=

==== .status
TERMINATED [atexit]

==== No prof.log

==== No packet_filter.log

==== No loaded_scripts.log
```

My ifconfig shows up this :

```
root@anuvrattiku-Inspiron-13-7368:/etc# ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:6594 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:6594 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:950826 (950.8 KB)  TX bytes:950826 (950.8 KB)

wlp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 68:07:15:23:f2:f8  
      inet addr:10.250.39.91  Bcast:10.250.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      inet6 addr: fe80::274a:2cde:a0c8:1131/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:271804 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:49076 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:342567344 (342.5 MB)  TX bytes:6733501 (6.7 MB)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think this belongs on http://askubuntu.com

Comment: It looks like your machine doesn't have an interface `eth0`, which is assumed to the default. You need to configure BroControl with your network interface correctly.

Answer (score 1):

you're gonna need to check the bro config files mainly "/`usr/local/bro/etc/node.cfg`" and modify the hostname and the interface variables

based on the diag results it's showing "==== .cmdline
-i **eth0** -U .status -p broctl " which means it's using the default configs. 
thus. all what you need to make it work is just to change the interface to **wlp1s0**

be aware that's you're gonna need to make more configurations to start using it.

Answer (score -1):

run `sudo nano /usr/local/bro/etc/networks.cfg`
on your interface change it from `eth0` to `wlp1s0`